In this position, why is the move 12. Be3 rarely played by top players?
[Title ""]
[Fen ""]
[Startply "22"]

1.e4 e5 2.Nf3 Nc6 3.Bb5 a6 4.Ba4 Nf6 5.O-O Be7 6.Re1 b5 7.Bb3 d6 8.c3 O-O 9.h3 Na5
10.Bc2 c5 11.d4 Nd7 *

In the above position, Lichess' database shows that the move 12. Be3 was played only once by masters. This move develops the bishop to an active square, supports the d4 pawn, and prepares to connect the rooks. Additionally, it puts pressure on the c5 pawn and can potentially open up lines for White's pieces.
So why don't masters play 12.Be3?

What if 12...Nc4, attacking the bishop on e3 and pawn on b2, if 13. b3 then 13...Nxe3 and black has a bishop pair, and 13. Bc1 cannot be great because at the very least black can go back with 13...Na5 to the original position, meaning that 12. Be3 gives no more than equality.

Black's plan in the given position are (a) expand queenside and (b) gain control of e5 square. White tries to fight for an advantage while negating these plans. A general direction that master games take from here has been given below: (see from 12. Nbd2)
[fen ""]
[title ""]
[startply "23"]

1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bb5 a6 4. Ba4 Nf6 5. O-O Be7 6. Re1 b5 7. Bb3 d6
8. c3 O-O 9. h3 Na5 10. Bc2 c5 11. d4 Nd7 12. Nbd2 exd4 13. cxd4 Nc6
14. d5 Nce5 15. a4 Rb8 16. axb5 axb5 17. Nxe5 Nxe5 18. f4 Ng6 19. Nf3 *

Notice how Nbd2 is preferred over Nc3 to avoid getting hit with b4 in the future. Also the bishop at c1 is better than at e3 in the final position (it defends b2 and prevent black's access to a1-h8 diagonal). You mention that 12. be3 would help to connect the rooks. Note how that's not a priority in that position since your rook would later get developed via the open a file.
Now suppose you play 12. Be3 and decide to give up the dark squared bishop. The following variation could then take place: (see from 12. Be3)
[fen ""]
[title ""]
[startply "23"]

1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bb5 a6 4. Ba4 Nf6 5. O-O Be7 6. Re1 b5 7. Bb3 d6 8. c3 O-O 9. h3 Na5 10. Bc2 c5 11. d4 Nd7 12. Be3 Nc4 13. b3 Nxe3 14. fxe3 cxd4 15. exd4

In the final position, black has a clear plan of controlling the dark squares with Qb6 and Bf6. And I would gladly choose black over white (though it's objectively equal according to engine).
Want to save your bishop by playing b3 first? (see from 12. b3)
[fen ""]
[title ""]
[startply "23"]

1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bb5 a6 4. Ba4 Nf6 5. O-O Be7 6. Re1 b5 7. Bb3 d6 8. c3 O-O 9. h3 Na5 10. Bc2 c5 11. d4 Nd7 12. b3 exd4 13. cxd4 Nc6 14. Be3 Nb4

Well you would lose the light squared bishop if you try to force your 14. Be3. And then black's target would be the a8-h1 diagonal.
You realise this and try to switch back to your original plans with of Nbd2 without Be3. Alas, it's too late. The pawn you give up as a result can't be recaptured without major concessions to black. (see from 14. Nbd2)
[fen ""]
[title ""]
[startply "27"]

1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bb5 a6 4. Ba4 Nf6 5. O-O Be7 6. Re1 b5 7. Bb3 d6 8. c3 O-O 9. h3 Na5 10. Bc2 c5 11. d4 Nd7 12. b3 exd4 13. cxd4 Nc6 14. Nbd2? cxd4 15. Bb2 Bf6 16. Nf1 Qb6 17. Qd2 Nde5 18. Nxd4 Nxd4 19. Bxd4 Nf3+ 20. gxf3 Qxd4

Finally, going 12. Be3 only to return back to c1 after 12... Nc4 is just a loss of 2 tempo.

What about 12.d5 pls?

Detailed analysis of 12. d5 is its own question, but black's plan should probably change to the following  (1). Route either knight to b6 to defend a8 so that white's a4 isn't as powerful (probably Kd7-b6 is better since it opens up the bishop which assists with the 2nd plan) (2). play for f4 and maybe kingside expansion/attack in KID fashion (but it won't be as simple since black's knights are on the wrong side of the board, they're kingside in KID)

See here

I think masters would not generally play 12.Be3 for the simple reason that there is a better move, which should be played immediately if it's going to be played at all.
If I was playing this, I would immediately go for 12.d5, to cement in Black’s structural pawn weakness. I see Lichess also considers 12.d5 the best move.
